# Rave Reports with Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-6

We are trying to migrate Delphi 6 to Delphi 2010 with Rave Reports.
Delphi 6 was using TReportPrinter to print the results. We don't have that Rave component in Delphi 2010.

Could you please guide how to proceed and which component of Rave 7.7 we can use for printing?

Thanks,

AS

Comment: Pedantic point: Don't refer to  Delphi 2010 as version 10. Delphi 2006 was actually "version 10".

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.chmlib.com/RaveDevRef/trvrenderprinter.htm

The component is replaced by TRenderPrinter. The associated documentation should help you going on.